# is it possible to display pure html code via textview on android

Tags: android, html, textview

I'm trying to show HTML string with TextView on my android App.
I'm curious about that how could I make it possible to show HTML with inline style via TextView.
There're some reason that we can't use WebView for this.
Is there any repository on GitHub that you know it works?

Thanks for helping.

Just for your concern, we need to run it perfectly on API 15.

Comment: You can use "Html.fromHtml" but TextView supports only a limited amount of tags https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html .Can we know y u can't use webview ?

Comment: That's a creepy requirement from our PM.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **Html.fromHtml()** to use HTML in your `textView` as a text

example :

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Comment: We have to support inline style. Like style="font-size:20px;font-weight:600;color:#FF0000;text-ali‌​gn:center;"

Comment: @Frank android doesn't support all HTML tages directly.

Comment: Supported tag list is here https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Yes. So I don't know how to make this happen. It's an existing feature on iOS App. Android should look the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the source that I get , but I made this way:

```
// get our html content
String htmlAsString = getString(R.string.html);
Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString); // used by TextView

// set the html content on the TextView
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(htmlAsSpanned);
```

html string on a xml file :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestProject2</string>

    <string name="html">
        <![CDATA[
        <h1>Main Title</h1>
        <h2>A sub-title</h2>
        <p>This is some html. Look, here\'s an <u>underline</u>.</p>
        <p>Look, this is <em>emphasized.</em> And here\'s some <b>bold</b>.</p>
        <p>This is a UL list:
        <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
        <p>This is an OL list:
        <ol>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        </ol>
        ]]>
    </string>
</resources>
```

Defining on textview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivity"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="top|fill_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <!--
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/helloWorld"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
    -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And on main activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get our html content
        String htmlAsString = getString(R.string.html);      // used by WebView
        Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString); // used by TextView

        // set the html content on a TextView
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(htmlAsSpanned);

//        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
//        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlAsString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    }

}
```

Comment: Not an option. We have to support inline style. Like style="font-size:20px;font-weight:600;color:#FF0000;text-align:center;"